# Set nextval sequence data type to integer only

Tags: postgresql, nextval

I have an issues running around my mind regarding default for 'id' field in my postgresql database. Here is the syntax:-

```
nextval('unsub_keyword_id_seq'::regclass)
```

However I'm not really understands even after read the [documentations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-oid.html) & I would like to set the value only for integer(digit only). I try to alter the column by change regclass to other OIDs but each time it will return errors.

Really appreciate if can get this solved very soon.

Update:

It just come to my idea on the data type for the column after I try & error with the code that will produce the id for the column.
Is integer(postgresql in this case) have it's own default length or not?
If I need to to insert long id, should I set the column length?
Kindly advise.

*sorry if my questions quite confusing. your comments may help me to improve it.*

Comment: I don't understand, [`nextval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) only gives you integers. Your `id` is getting new integers from a sequence to ensure uniqueness. The `::regclass` is a type cast. What exactly are you trying accomplish?

Comment: @muistooshort let me update my questions first. sorry for inconveniences.

Comment: @muistooshort just update my question. my pleasure to get your next comments. =)

Comment: I still don't understand what problem you are facing. Perhaps it would help if you showed concrete examples. What are you trying? What errors do you get? what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Your column is probably has type `serial`, that just an integer column combine with a sequence for providing default values (more or less). Perhaps you want [`bigserial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger I need to insert an id with length of 50 with consist of 2 alphabets & the rest is numeric. the problems occur as the data type is in integer & the data inserting in unsuccessful. is it possible to insert my desired data by retain the data type to integer?

You may help to edit my questions which you think will help other mods understands the problems I am facing right now.
thanks.

Comment: @muistooshort sorry if this questions too dumb, did serial similar to integer? if need to change to big serial means to bigint?

Comment: I think you need to go right back to the begginning here. Think about the underlying problem you are trying to solve. What are the inputs? What are the required outputs? How are they created? What must you store? etc. Think about that, rather than some fairly confused idea about how you might solve a problem it's not even clear you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> I need to insert an id with length of 50 with consist of 2 alphabets & the rest is numeric. the problems occur as the data type is in integer & the data inserting in unsuccessful. is it possible to insert my desired data by retain the data type to integer?

If I understand this correctly, you probably need to format a string, e.g.

```
format('%s%s', 'XX', nextval('some_sequence_name'))
```

Comment: if the data type of column is integer, is it still possible?

Comment: @WafieAli You can't have letters in an integer. That makes no sense. So no. You could use some kind of bit-shifting tricks to "translate" your integers into your desired weird format, but I'm not going to get into that because it's crazy and you shouldn't do it, plus it's going to be impractically hard for you to do.

Comment: If that's the case, I will discuss back with my team regarding this. you answers come to my sense. thanks for your effort in clarify this messes. =)